# Javascript: I cant get a textbox to display a value updated on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I'm trying to simply have a button update the contents of ah HTML textbox (on the client side).
Clicking the button fires the updateBox() method fine. Stepping through the code, I can see the text1.value field update fine but the text1 does not seem to get updated by changes to the dom.

Am I mistaken to think that you can do updates on the client side only by modifying dom data?

```
<input type=text name="text1" value="100"/>
<button name="but1" id="but1" onclick="updateBox" >clickme!</button>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    var text1 = document.getElementsByName('text1');

    function updateBox() {
        //text1.value = "22"; <----tried this way, no good either :(
        text1.innerHTML = "99";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Few things:

- `onclick="updateBox"` should be `onclick="updateBox()"`
- `var text1 = document.getElementsByName('text1');` should be `var text1 = document.getElementsByName('text1')[0];` (note the `[0]`)
- `text1.value = "22";` is the one to use

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v6f4r/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try use below,

```
var text1 = document.getElementsByName('text1')[0];
function updateBox() {       
    text1.value= "99";
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Comment: Why does he need to move `var text1 = document.getElementsByName('text1');` inside the function?

Comment: Why would that matter?  You've fixed the actual issue in your code, but your description makes no mention of that fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's responses. 
With your advice I got the button to update. I appreciate the advice on how to implement the function correctly. This was just a test so I didn't pay much attention.

1) I had to use: onclick="updateBox" rather than "updateBox() in the button HTML because "updateBox" caused the event to fire with out clicking the button.

2) Big thanks for pointing out that I was referencing a collection instead of an item in the collection. Had to use: var tb1 = document.getElementsByName('tb1')[0];

3) For some reason the box would not update when I used:tb1.innerHTML = "99";
This worked: tb1.value = "99";

Answer (score -1):

text1[0].innerHTML = "99"

Use innerHTML instead of value

Comment: "Use innerHTML instead of value". Why?

Comment: @user3075398, sorry this is wrong. `.value` is the right way to go as you'll see from some of the other answers. There were also some additional things wrong with the OPs code that have been explained.

Answer (score -2):

try passing the variable to your function instead of declaring it outside of your function.

```
<input type=text name="text1" value="100"/>
<button name="but1" id="but1" onclick="updateBox('text1',99)" >clickme!</button>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    function updateBox(t,v) {
        var tv = document.getElementsByName(t)[0];
        tv.value = v;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What difference would that make?  Are you just guessing?

Comment: **Wow**, thanks for the negative feedback.  I like to make functions reusable, so passing the variables via the function call makes it not a one case option.

Comment: Since your function doesn't work, I wouldn't call it "reusable."

Comment: How about rather than being a troll, you contribute to a solution. There were zero responses when I was writing this, and I accidentally missed the [0].  I've updated my solution based on everyones actual feedback.